# Repeated Error on Exit Qt App

Tags: python, pyqt

Once in a while I am getting the same error right after the app is closed by clicking a red exit/close button on top left corner of app window (it only happens if the app was run on OSX).

[image]

The error dialog below is all I have so it is quite difficult to track down the problem:

[image]

Aside from this message there is a printout on cmd line:

```
[Finished in 28.0s with exit code -11]
```

I wonder if anyone has experienced the same problem and already knows how to solve it.
Once again, the Application dialog window was already closed. The app exited by the user clicking the red close button. The error window that is posted below pops up 2-3 second after the App already exited.

Here is the MainWindow class I am using. Since I am catching window closing event I can costumize how the app is exiting if that is what causes OSX error message....If I just would know what exactly causes that annoying error message....

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
    def closeEvent(self, e):
        result = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self,"Confirm window","Are you sure you want to close the window?",QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No,QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            e.accept()
            QtGui.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, e)
        else:
            e.ignore()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `accept()` on an event indicates that the parents should not process this event, but that this widget will. I don't know in your case whether the window is the root one or not, but `accept()` is probably not necessary. Also, in this case you are about to exit, so there's actually no reason to call the `closeEvent` - you should call `destroy()` instead, or do a system exit and wait for auto-destroy.

To ensure that the program closes, you can always do

```
sys.exit()
```

Comment: This is a root parent window. When the user clicks close button closeEvent would do few more things before App exits (writing config preferences to file, makes sure all the process are completed and etc). So I need this closeEvent to make sure the App completes everything it need before exiting. I will try to use sys.exit(). Let's see how that would work.

Comment: Docs say `destroy()` "Releases the native platform resources associated with this window." Should I put it inside of `closeEvent` method just before `sys.exit()`?

Comment: Either. If you are going to do `sys.exit()` anyway, then you shouldn't need to destroy the GUI first.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help! For last hour the annoying error message is gone. I guess sys.exit() does its job pretty well.